# Laravel ORM конструктор запросов

Tags: laravel

Имеется SQL запросы:

```
$users = DB::select('
                    SELECT users.id AS uid, COUNT(subscriber_id) AS cnt FROM users
                    LEFT JOIN user_subscribers ON users.id = user_subscribers.user_id
                    WHERE users.id IN (' . implode(',', $subscribers) . ')
                    GROUP BY users.id
                    ORDER BY users.id
                ');
```

и

```
$user_subscribers = DB::select('
                    SELECT user_subscribers.subscriber_id AS sid FROM user_subscribers
                    WHERE user_id IN (' . implode(',', $subscribers) . ')
                    ORDER BY subscriber_id
                ');
```

Как эти запросы будут выглядеть если создавать их с помощью конструктора запросов? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если делать без [отношений](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships) между моделями пользователя и подписчиков, то  это может выглядеть так:

```
$users = User::select('id')
    ->selectRaw('count(subscriber_id) as count')
    ->leftJoin('user_subscribers, 'user_subscribers.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->whereIn('user_id', $subscribers)
    ->groupBy('users.id')
    ->orderBy('users.id')
    ->get();

$user_subscribers = Subscriber::select('subscriber_id')
    ->whereIn('user_id', $subscribers)
    ->orderBy('subscriber_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: А можно ли как-то без отношений прописать первый запрос? Имеется ввиду чтобы лишний раз не лезть в модель? Да и не знаю я как это сделать) Покажите пожалуйста как $users переделать в ORM без отношений) Спасибо

Comment: Переделал ответ без отношений